# what do we gain with a lambda that receives a parameter as auto&& x as opposed to auto& x?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have this expression `auto is_assignable = is_valid([](auto&& x)->decltype(x = x) {});`

why would `auto&&` be preferable to `auto&`?

Is `auto&&` equivalent to universal references as in `template<typename T> ?? func(T&& t)` ?
In other words, can `auto&&` take rvalue and lvalue references and is thus more general than `auto&` ?

Comment: btw term is not "universal reference". It was for a very brief period, but it was misleading so they've rightfully changed it. It is forwarding reference.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `auto&&` in a lambda parameter is a forwarding reference with the special rules applying to them.

`auto&&` will accept any value category as argument and deduce to a lvalue- or rvalue-reference as appropriate.